# Wamp, PHP MySQL - Connecting error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, wampserver

I've installed a WAMP server. Now I want to connect to a MySQL database using php. I have one problem you need to get the username.
This is the code I use. Its from php.net http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "password";
$db_name = "test";

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
?>
```

I get the following error:

> Warning: `mysqli::mysqli()`: in C:\wamp\www\Atletieker\dbconnect.php on line 7
>   Failed to connect to MySQL: (1045) Accès refusé pour l'utilisateur: 'root'@'@localhost' (mot de passe: OUI)
>
> Warning: `main()`: Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\wamp\www\Atletieker\dbconnect.php on line 11

How do I get the username of my database?

Comment: Do you have a MySQL server running on where the PHP code is running?

Comment: try `$db_password = "";`

Comment: Using WAMP, your hostname should be 'localhost'. (you are connecting to your own machine). This is the case, since you are not getting any connection errors. This error is telling you that you are entering a wrong password. EDIT: I believe the default WAMP MySQL password is 'root', and not 'password'.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 I have a WAMP Server running on my computer.

Comment: @NiekvanderSteen I have changes the password in the my.ini file

Comment: @Finiox did you also restart MySQL after you did that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
    $db_host = "127.0.0.1";
    $db_username = "root";
    $db_password = "";
    $db_name = "test";
```

Comment: I have changed the password in the my.ini file. The problem is the $db_username is not right I think. Because I've put root there

Comment: Make sure to restart MySQL on your server.

Answer (score -1):

Obviously the `$db_password` should be empty, if you haven't changed any settings the default password should be blank.

Comment: I have changes the password in the my.ini file